# What is “n'ai” composed of?

Tags: contractions

In the following sentence:

> Je n'ai pas

What is the word "n'ai" composed of?

Comment: [Basics of avoir](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-french-verb-ne%20pas%20avoir.html). Please check before you ask a question.

Comment: And about the negative : http://www.french-linguistics.co.uk/grammar/negative.shtml

Answer (score -2):

> Je **n'ai** pas. | Je **ne ai** pas. (Though in French this sentence is wrong, "**ne ai**" always contract into "**n'ai**")

Same as in English :

> I **don't** have. | I **do not** have.

Or (Without the `do`)

> I **haven't**. | I **have not.**

Comment: When have you ever heard or read "Je ne ai pas"?

Comment: @ElenaMellor Read OP's question. He asked : `What is the word "n'ai" composed of?`. I wrote the sentence to show that this was composed of `NE`and `AI`. In the same way that the sentence `Je ne mange pas` is written. Do you understand?

Comment: What @ElenaMellor means, and I agree with her, is that we cannot write anything that is wrong, knowing it is wrong without **signalling** it is wrong. The way you wrote your answer signifies that *Je n'ai pas* equals *Je ne ai pas*. Of course we know you know it is not correct, but how can a beginner in French know if you don't tell them?  People who come here to learn French, must not be mislead by wrong explanations. And comments are there to point out at wrong answers among other things.

Comment: @Laure, je suis d'accord avec toi. J'ai ajouté une petite phrase pour expliquer que `ne ai` ne se dit pas. Si c'est encore nébuleux, j'enlèverai ma réponse puisque la question est un dupliqué de toute façon.

Comment: Dans une réponse, pour indiquer que ce qu'on écrit n'est pas correct ou agrammatical on peut utiliser le html <del>texte barré</del> mais ça ne marche pas dans les commentaires ! On peut aussi mettre un *devant la phrase fausse et expliquer en note. Chacun son truc, tu verras à l'usage ce que tu préfères.